# How to stop .bashrc from running sub-command in alias at startup?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, alias

I have added an alias command to kill my `guake` terminal to my `.bashrc`

```
alias killguake="kill -9 $(ps aux | grep guake | head -n -1 | awk '{print $2}')"
```

But the problem is, the sub-command i.e. `ps aux | grep guake | head -n -1 | awk '{print $2}'` is executed at the time of terminal startup and `killguake` is set to `kill -9 result_of_subcommand`.

Is there any way to set it like so, that the sub command is run/calculated  every time I run `killguake`? So that it can have the latest PID for the guake.

I have also tried piping to the `kill` using `xargs` but that also result in same, that is calculating everything at startup. Here is what I tried with piping

```
ps aux | grep guake | head -n -1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} kill -9 {}
```

Comment: ... Or use quotes `'` instead of double-quotes `"`.

Comment: To avoid using `head`, use grep like this `grep [g]uake`.

Comment: @richard nice tip, thanks. But what does `[g]` means?

Comment: Can't `pidof` replace that long command sequence? As in `kill -9 $(pidof guake)`, or even better, `pkill`?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir [g] just means g in this context.  [abc] would match a, b, or c ... but when there's just one character, it's basically redundant... except that now the grep won't find itself in ps, and therefore you can skip needing to do the head part to filter it out.

Comment: @richard That won't work without quoting the expression _if_ there happens to be a file in the current directory whose name is `guake`.

Comment: An alias is the wrong tool for the job for complex logic anyhow. `killguake() { kill -9 $(ps aux | grep guake | head -n -1 | awk '{print $2}') }` is *purely* a definition, and doesn't execute anything when that definition is run. (But yes, use `pkill`).

Comment: @richard, make it `'[g]uake'`, in single quotes, to avoid shell expansion back into `guake` in the case Kusalananda mentions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `pkill` instead:

```
alias killguake='pkill guake'
```

This is a whole lot safer than trying to parse the process table outputted by `ps`.

Having said that, I will now explain why your alias doesn't do what you want, but really, *use `pkill`*.

Your alias

```
alias killguake="kill -9 $(ps aux | grep guake | head -n -1 | awk '{print $2}')"
```

is double quoted. This means that when the shell parses that line in your shell initialization script, it will perform command substitutions (`$( ... )`). So each time the file runs, instead of giving you an alias to kill `guake` at a later time, it will give you an alias to kill the `guake` process running *right now*.

If you list your aliases (with `alias`), you'll see that this alias is something like

```
killguake='kill -9 91273'
```

or possibly even just

```
killquake='kill -9'
```

if `guake` wasn't running at the time of shell startup.

To fix this (but really, *just use `pkill`*) you need to use single quotes and escape the `$` in the Awk script (which is now in double quotes):

```
alias killguake='kill -9 $(ps aux | grep guake | head -n -1 | awk "{print \$2}")'
```

*One* of the issues with this approach in general is that you will match the processes belonging to other users. Another is that you will possibly just find the `grep guake` command instead of the intended process. Another is that it will throw an error if no process was found. Another is that you're invoking five external utilities to do the job of one.

Comment: Using the `\` with internal single quotes, I get `invalid syntax near )` when I use this. Any idea? PS. I would use pkill with guake but some other things I need this approach.

Comment: @MuhammadTahir Really do not use this approach. I only mentioned what was wrong so that you would learn something. Do not ever try to parse the output of `ps` to find a process!! I'm serious. There is no instance where you need to do that, ever!

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought my use case cannot be done with `pkill`, but I got my use case working with `pkill`. Thanks. But just out of curiosity, any idea about the `syntax error`?

Comment: @MuhammadTahir The answer is updated, have a look.

Comment: Muhammad Tahir could also turn it into a function, but again, `pkill` is probably simpler.

Answer (score 6):

Use pkill, don't reinvent the wheel!

```
alias killguake="pkill -9 guake"
```